# Why do guitar pickup output levels not add?

Tags: audio

I have noticed that when wiring guitar pickups together in parallel, the total output level is the level of the pickup with the lowest output. The output will be as loud as the quietest pickup. Why is this the case? Shouldn't the amplitudes add?

Comment: Why do you think they should add?

Comment: @Hearth makes intuitive sense no?

Comment: Not if your output signal is meant to be a voltage, no.

Comment: Voltage doesn't flow so doesn't add. Current, however does flow. But audio signals aren't current signals. Crude analog: If you mix water together in a Y-pipe, the volume of water adds, but the temperature of the water doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

If you have active pickups and parallel them through a resistor divider, you basically arrive at the arithmetic mean of the two signals, i.e. you mix them transparently. The level will consequently be intermediate.

When you parallel passive coils, it's more complicated. The inductances in parallel result in about half inductance as a single pickup and the resonance frequency thus shifts up where there is usually less string motion. As a result parallel passive pickups usually give lower peak amplitude than any single pickup by itself.